# Firestore Cloud functions | trigger events based on time field is equal to

Tags: javascript, firebase, twilio, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

## The Question

Can you fire a firebase cloud function when a fields meet certain values for a specific amount of duration?

## Background of the project

I have built a temperature sensor application that users can use to monitor the temperature of an object. There are situations where users will want to be notified if the temperature hits a certain level for a specific amount of time.

I am successful in getting a cloud function to send the text via twilio when a field changes, but now I want to insert better-aligned business rules.

## My plan is to check the following:

- Is the sensor powered on?
- Is the temperature greater than 'x'?
- Has the temperature been above 'x' for more than 'y' amount of time?

If these conditions are true I want to send a text message.

## The Problem

I am trying to identify the best trigger, I could simply fire the function when the temperature changes or when the sensor is turned on, but these cloud functions will run indefinitely until the triggers which could be never.

I have tried to understand the billing rules with firebase, but I couldn't pinpoint if running cloud functions would increase billing based on time. I would hate to fire this function and get a major bill down the road.

#### Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you can't limit the specific conditions under which an event fires.  Your Firestore trigger will receive one event for each change that meets the general criteria of the trigger.  So, for onUpdate triggers, any change to a document that matches the general criteria (the document path) will fire that trigger.  You can't be selective about which document properties may invoke your function.  You have to check inside the function if it's an event you'd like to respond to, and return early if you don't want to do anything with it.

Comment: Do you know if billing for cloud functions is based on the number of executions or duration of runtime?